# I am getting error :"Module 'smart-table' is not available!" in my js file

Tags: angularjs

I am using export table plugin [found here](https://github.com/Epotignano/angular-export-table).
    I have added the module "smart-table" but I am getting an error:

> `Module 'smart-table' is not available!`

```
(function() {
  angular.module('portal', [
    'ui.router',
    'ceibo.components.table.export',
    'smart-table']);
})();
```

The smart-table plugin file is:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('smart-table')
    .directive('stFilteredCollection', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: {
          stFilteredCollection: '='
        },
        controller: 'stTableController',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

          scope.$watch(function() {
            return ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
          }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
            scope.stFilteredCollection = ctrl.getFilteredCollection();
          });
        }
      };
    });
})();
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your ultimate goal with your directive is unclear, but your source of confusion is likely to do with your module definition.

[According to the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module), you presently only have one module defined for your app - that's `portal`.  Your `portal` module *depends* on `smart-table`, but that dependency doesn't allow you to suddenly add new things to that module.

An early hunch would indicate that you need to change the module you're referencing to one that is defined in your application.

```
angular.module('portal')
    .directive('stFilteredCollection', function()
```